# How to post/add an object to a nested array inside a mongodb database with express and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating a monthly calendar with the mern stack and am now working on the backend of my application. In my mongodb atlas database cluster I have a collection named events and within it an object for each day of the month. In it is a property with a key of events and with an array with the events in the day.

This is how my database is collection is structured

```
0: {_id: "6101c9536d8a296ad4727625", events: Array(0)}
1: {_id: "6101c97d6d8a296ad4727627", events: Array(0)}
2: {_id: "6101c9d26d8a296ad4727629", events: Array(1)}
3: {_id: "6101c9f26d8a296ad472762a", events: Array(0)}
4: {_id: "6101ca016d8a296ad472762b", events: Array(0)}
5: {_id: "6101ca096d8a296ad472762c", events: Array(0)}
6: {_id: "6101ca106d8a296ad472762d", events: Array(0)}
7: {_id: "6101ca186d8a296ad472762e", events: Array(0)}
8: {_id: "6102d57c7621f3375c5bbc53", events: Array(0)}
9: {_id: "6102d57e7621f3375c5bbc55", events: Array(0)}
10: {_id: "6102d57e7621f3375c5bbc57", events: Array(0)}
11: {_id: "6102d57f7621f3375c5bbc59", events: Array(0)}
12: {_id: "6102d57f7621f3375c5bbc5b", events: Array(0)}
13: {_id: "6102d5807621f3375c5bbc5d", events: Array(0)}
14: {_id: "6102d5937621f3375c5bbc60", events: Array(0)}
15: {_id: "6102d5957621f3375c5bbc62", events: Array(0)}
16: {_id: "6102d5967621f3375c5bbc64", events: Array(0)}
17: {_id: "6102d5967621f3375c5bbc66", events: Array(0)}
18: {_id: "6102d5977621f3375c5bbc68", events: Array(0)}
19: {_id: "6102d5977621f3375c5bbc6a", events: Array(0)}
20: {_id: "6102d59a7621f3375c5bbc74", events: Array(0)}
21: {_id: "6102d59b7621f3375c5bbc76", events: Array(0)}
22: {_id: "6102d59c7621f3375c5bbc78", events: Array(0)}
23: {_id: "6102d59c7621f3375c5bbc7a", events: Array(0)}
24: {_id: "6102d59d7621f3375c5bbc7c", events: Array(0)}
25: {_id: "6102d59d7621f3375c5bbc7e", events: Array(0)}
26: {_id: "6102d59e7621f3375c5bbc80", events: Array(0)}
27: {_id: "6102d59f7621f3375c5bbc82", events: Array(0)}
28: {_id: "6102d5a07621f3375c5bbc84", events: Array(0)}
29: {_id: "6102d5a07621f3375c5bbc86", events: Array(0)}
30: {_id: "6102d5fb7621f3375c5bbc89", events: Array(0)}
```

I can add and delete the day objects but what is not working for me is adding and deleting objects inside the events array.

This is my event schema and what is needed for it are the properties and the chosen day which says which day to add the object too

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  chosenDay: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  event: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
  },
  start: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  end: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  people: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
  },
  location: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Event", EventSchema);
```

And this is my add function (I added middleware for the body parser)

```
const Event = require("../models/Event");
exports.addEvent = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { event, start, end, people, location, description, chosenDay } =
      req.body;
    const eventAdded = await Event[req.body.chosenDay].events.create(req.body);
    return res.status(201).json({
      success: true,
      data: eventAdded,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      error: "Server has failed",
    });
  }
};
```

If I write this instead

```
const eventAdded = await Event.create(req.body);
```

And this is my db.js page

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    console.log(
      `MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`.cyan.underline.bold
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`.red);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

My config.env page is:

```
NODE_ENV=development
PORT=5000
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://(my username and password)@cluster0.gnstm.mongodb.net/calendar?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

it works but I am trying to add it inside the events array which is inside an object

If I go to postman and try to post

```
{
    "chosenDay": 3,
    "event": "Dinner",
    "start": "6:30",
    "end": "7:05",
    "people": "Family"
}
```

It gives me an error. 
**Does Anyone know if there is a way to fix this?
Thank You For Your Help.**

Comment: You db collection doesn't match your schema.

Comment: I uploaded my db.js file as well. How do I make it work? Thank you. P.S. This is my first project with mongoose, so I am still a beginner at it